# two read rules and second rule does a field check

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a rule setup for firebase. Which works for reads when a member is already part of the subcollection.

```
   match /clans/{clanName} {
    allow create;
    allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/clans/$(clanName)/members/$(request.auth.uid));
        match /members/{uid} {
            allow create;
            allow read,write,delete: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```

Now i am trying to use a random key generated that is stored on the clan profile to allow reads also.

[image]

I am trying by getting the clan document and checking the key then adding if it matches. I would like to just do a request and the rule validate the docid and key are right.

Comment: "and the rule validate the docid and key are right". What do you exactly mean?

Comment: When the user types in the clan name and key i want to check the clan document to make sure the key and name are correct if so ill add them. I know its not a super great invite system but it keeps clans hidden from each other and i thought was easy for now to do then come back and revamp.